# Set theory with unix tools: "relaxed" intersection of two lists where item in set 1 is at least a subtring of items in set 2

Tags: text-processing

I have a list of mac addresses of machines by means of a dhcp log. I need to filter on a set of mac address prefixes (the substring) which belong to a vendor.
How can I can filter the list of machine mac addresses based on the set of vendor prefixes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following construct, assuming the mac addresses are normalized, i.e., both files are using a unique separator like a colon or dash:

```
$ grep -Ff file-with-prefixes file-with-machine-mac-addresses
```

This might or might not adhere to your semantics of a "relaxed" intersection.

/Updated to use grep -F based on @wildcard's comment.

Comment: May want to add the `-F` flag for fixed string search if you happen to be using periods for separators (which I suppose should be unlikely).  Alternatively, you could add a `^` at the beginning of each line of the prefixes file to avoid matching suffixes or arbitrary substrings.